# Does App Engine NDB keys in KeyProperty count against 1MB storage limit?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm creating NDB Model instances in Google App Engine that are hitting the 1MB size limit.  It has to do with a repeated `StringProperty` which is 10-20k in length.

Here's an example:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    items = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)

instance = MyModel()
instance.items = []
For item in largeDataset:
    instance.items.append(item)

instance.put()
# Instance is >1MB Error
```

My question is to get around this, can I use ndb keyproperties and other models instead?  Do the keys count against the 1MB limit?

It would be something like:

```
class ItemModel(ndb.Model):
    item = ndb.StringProperty()

class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    items = ndb.KeyProperty(ItemModel, repeated=True)

instance = MyModel()
instance.items = []
For item in largeDataset:
    instance.items.append(
        ItemModel(item=item).put()
    )

instance.put()
# Same problems?
```

Would I still get relatively the same error?  The item strings are not that long in length (~60 chars), but the amount is variable (20,000+) and I would prefer a method that won't hit the instance size limit.

So do the keys count against the 1MB limit?  If so, what is the relative size of an NDB keyProperty?

Comment: Since you are providing the code why not just run it and see if it works or not? Also, are your items being updated after you `put()` them and are you sure Google Cloud Storage wouldn't better fit your needs? If not - maybe you could check if your data exceeds the limit and if it does - do something like linked lists where you have a reference to the next entity with the rest of your data that didn't fit into your previous entity, this way you you would read all the data in a loop and would not be limited to 1mb data size and could store dozens of MB if needed (not sure how efficient this is).

Comment: Because the list of items is variable, and I don't have a list right now that would represent the largest value for the model to test it.  This code is a gross simplification of what I am attempting to do, and before I go down the route of using repeated KeyProperties I want to weigh in on SO's experience first.

Comment: If you don't need to query by them -- use compressed local structured property.

Comment: I just might try compressed local structured property.  The only problem I foresee is the 10 minute execution limit, and the added CPU load from gzip compressions on so many items might hit the limit, but I can solve that problem.  I'll update the question if I do use compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, key values of properties consume entity storage space. The amount of space used by a key is proportional to the string equivalent, for example: `ParentKind:name/ChildKind:other_id`.  The actual space used depends on an internal encoding, but this is pretty close.

If the original values are small, you are right to suspect that the keys might take just as much space as the original values.  If you're in a bind and are sure the data size won't grow further, it might be worth a try, for a small amount of savings.

Comment: Thanks - the approximate KeyProperty size was what I was looking for.  I searched the docs and couldn't find it.